# Making the right regexp pattern in js

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to implement this pattern on a regexp but I can't succeed making it work as I would like it to

```
var strInput = $("#inputFilter").val();
var pattern = new RegExp("(#[a-z0-9]{3,})|(@[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,16})|([a-zA-Z0-9]{6,16})(,((#[a-z0-9]{3,})|(@[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,16})|([a-zA-Z0-9]{6,16})))*");
var result = pattern.test(strInput);
if (!result)
{
    alert("Must follow this pattern, order is not relevant, e.g Title,#tag,@Username   or   Title,#tag,@Username,#tag2");
    return
}
```

---

Title is matched by the pattern [a-zA-Z0-9]{6,16} so for this example it will be the word HelloWorld which does match the pattern

#tag is matched by the pattern #[a-z0-9]{3,} so for this example it will be the word #hello which does match the pattern

@Username is matched by the pattern @[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,16} so for this example it will be the word @MyUser which does match the pattern

what I wanna achieve is getting the match of an input like this:

> HelloWorld,#tag1,#tag2,#tag3,@MyUsername,#onemoretag,#andonemore

but the order is not important so also something like this would be fine

> #tag1,#tag2,#tag3,@MyUsername,#tag4,HelloWorld

---

```
should match:
#hello
HelloWorld
@username
#hello,@MyUser,HelloWorld
@MyUsername,HiWorld,#hello1,#hello2

should NOT match:
#@hello
#hi
@User
@Username#hello
```

thanks for help

Comment: It's not entirely obvious what things should and shouldn't match; writing a regex is easy, but I can't really tell what you want it to do. Your error message says that a `Title` must come first, but that form is not provided in any of your examples. Are the comma-separated pieces allowed to come in any order? Is there a minimum or maximum limit on many of them are allowed?

Comment: I added some more info to make it more clear to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this a much simpler regex that matches your first provided examples, but fails on some of the later ones:

```
^([#@]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(,([#@]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+))*$
```

It's not especially complicated, but let's break it down for readability:

- `^ ... $` - These characters "anchor" the regex:  They ensure that it can't match any "floating" part of the middle of the string, but must match the *whole* string.
- `[#@]?` `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` These two pieces form the "meat" of the regex:  The first matches `#` or `@` or nothing, and the second matches one or more alphanumeric characters after it.
- `(...) ( , (...) )*` matches something, followed by zero-or-more of the same something, comma-separated.

---

Now, it looks from your original example (and from your added examples) that you want to match specialized forms for each "word", rather than just any alphanumeric characters.  That's not too difficult:  Instead of `[#@]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+`, you just mash the pieces you want together with `|` characters.  So it looks like these are the base pieces you want:

- `#[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}` - A tag, three or more alphanumeric characters, preceded by a `#`.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,16}` - A title, which is between six and sixteen alphanumeric characters.
- `@[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,16}` - A username, which is like a title, but preceded by an `@` sign.

Since title and username are nearly identical, you can just make the `@` optional, and the combined three forms look like this: `#[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}|@?[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,16}`

So, substituting those in, the resulting code looks like this:

```
var regex = /^(#[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}|@?[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,16})(,(#[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}|@?[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,16}))*$/;
```

Not too difficult.

---

A demo program is attached below to show that it works.

```js
var regex = /^(#[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}|@?[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,16})(,(#[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}|@?[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,16}))*$/;

$(".text").on("keyup", function() {
    var isMatch = regex.test(this.value);
    $(".match").text(isMatch ? "match" : "not match");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="text" />

<div class="match"></div>
```